# Validating user actions after authentication with jwt

Tags: c#, firebase, asp.net-core, jwt

I have an application with firebase authentication. And now I have an issue, that any user with valid jwt can access any other's user data.

For example I can make a request to one of my endpoints(i.e "photos/user/{id}") with valid jwt and by passing any {id} to endpoint I will receive that user's data. In my case we identify users by email inside our system. And I can successfully retrieve user's email from token. But the main question is - do I need to pass email, received from token, to every service now, so I can check it's actually token owner trying to access his data and not somebody else with a valid token. So far I've tried to create custom policy for authorization attribute, but there's too much cases to handle and I guess it will end up really fragile

Comment: You should change the endpoints to not be able to accept user id but get user id from the token, that way it will always only return the details linked to the token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your end-point to `photos/user` and pass the token to the action in a header.

You can then use the token to retrieve the correct user from the token and return the details for the user authenticated by the token, the same can then be applied to any other end-points, don't pass in the user id but use the token to get the user id from the authentication token

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But in our case receiving user id from token requires working with db context as the only way to receive id is by email from token. We don't use UserId's passed in token by firebase

Comment: What is the problem with accessing the database to get the user id? Or adding the user id to the JWT token?

Comment: Yea, you are right, there's no problem, actually. Thank you

Comment: Look into this about adding custom claims to the firebase jwt token that should allow you to add the user id to the token to make life easier https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

Comment: I will. Thank you once again